# Count number of a string within a group_by that are equal to something

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(place=c("Start", "B", "B", "A", "A", "Start", "A", "O", "A", "Start", "O", "A", "O"), ID=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2,4), rep(3,4)))

   place ID
1  Start  1
2      B  1
3      B  1
4      A  1
5      A  1
6  Start  2
7      A  2
8      O  2
9      A  2
10 Start  3
11     O  3
12     A  3
13     O  3
```

I want to count how many times there is an "O" within each group_by(ID). So ID 1 has zero O's, ID 2 has one "O" and ID 3 has two O's. The solution bellow filter for the rows with an O so I don't get count zero.

The solutions from the answers bellow gives this output:

```
  ID place
1  2     1
2  3     2
```

But I need a table that also shows the count for ID 1 which is zero. I could of course left_join the original IDs, and then set their count to zero, but there must be a solution that is more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` solution is:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(place = sum(place=="O"))
```

Comment: @Kery Jackson: Thanks! That solved the problem! And using dplyr.

Answer (score 3):

No need for any package, just do

```
  data [(data$place=="O"),]
```

it will give sliced dataframe with only O in rows then aggregate it. OR

```
  aggregate(place ~ ID, data[data$place == "O", ], FUN = length)
```

you will get answer

Comment: You might change your answer to `aggregate(place ~ ID, data[data$place == "O", ], FUN = length)`

Comment: Yah, we can do like this also.

Comment: @ Zeeshan & markus: This `data [(data$place=="O"),] %>%  group_by(ID) %>%  summarise(n=n())` works. Can you think of a solution that only uses dplyr? I prefer to stay consistent with dplyr. What do you think of this attitude? That is I rather not use aggregate.

Comment: @David : As per my knowledge the dplyr  converts query internally into SQL which will increase the computation power or will take more thime to execute.

Comment: @David Try `data %>% filter(place == "O") %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Comment: @markus: Yes thanks! But just saw that with filter I don't get the ID's that have count equal to zero.

Comment: @ marcus & Zeeshan: Both solutions filter the rows with "O" so I don't get the count when "O" is zero.

Comment: @david: remove  "O" -> make it 0

Comment: @ Zeeshan: Can you please look at the updated question?

Answer (score 2):

solution with `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(data)
count_dt <- dt[place == "O", .N, by = ID]
count_df <- as.data.frame(count_dt)
count_df
```

Comment: @ Jonny Phelps: Thanks! But I have not learned data.table yet. Can you please explain briefly when and why one should use data.table? Is it because of speed with large data sets?

Comment: Speed usually isn't going to be a bottleneck unless you work with really big data or with production code, in which case R may not work well anyway without a lot of resource. I see the speedup as a bonus; I prefer the syntax, find it more intuitive than `dplyr`.